# Dynamic Links from a CMS - Error: "redirect" can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering

Tags: redirect, next.js

I have a Next JS app connected to a CMS and hosted on Vercel - all links are dynamic and the pages are created by the content authors.

I am trying to create dynamic redirects that will force URLs to adhere to formats that are better for SEO. For example:

- Enforce lowercase URLs
- Replace spaces with dashes
- Remove trailing slashes

For example, /test/Author Name/ would redirect to /test/author-name

Since I need to trigger a 301 redirect for these wrong URLs, the only way to do this with Next JS from what I have found is to return a **Redirect** from **getStaticProps**, this is what I have so far:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  let requestedUrl = '/';
  if (context?.params?.path) {
    requestedUrl = '/' + (context?.params?.path as string[]).join('/');
  }

  //check for URLs with uppercases, spaces, etc. and clean them up
  let modifiedUrl = requestedUrl;
  modifiedUrl = modifiedUrl.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(/\s/g, '-');
  if (modifiedUrl != requestedUrl) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: modifiedUrl,
        permanent: true,
      },
    };
  }
```

This works wonderfully well **running locally** and connected to the CMS - everything is working as it should and all "faulty" URLs are corrected with the correct response code.

Sadly, this **does not work on build**, I have spent so much time so far trying to find an alternative, but no matter what I do, the build on Vercel fails with the error:
*"redirect" can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering*

The next best potential solution is to use Middleware, but that requires v.12 at least. Due to limitations from the CMS connector, we are forced to use Node v.11 :(

The alternative that I have built is to use router.push on the client side, but this... just looks terrible. The page loads, returns a 200, and then loads again with the corrected URL. Not good for the user's experience.

Any advice or suggestions? I am baffled that something this simple is this complicated with Next JS!

Comment: That's not the only way to setup redirects in Next.js. You can also use [`redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) in `next.config.js`, or use Next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware).

Comment: Hey @juliomalves, sorry I didn't see your comment until now

We were not able to add the redirects in next.config.js as the redirects had to come from the CMS dynamically.
We can't use middleware because the version of the library used by the CMS is restricted to Node version 11 sadly, so until it is updated we can't use Middleware

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue... it looks like redirects on statically generated pages are not possible unfortunately. I removed getStaticProps and getStaticPaths, and added getServerSideProps instead. The redirects are now working correctly, but the site is not as fast as we are losing out on SSG.